# Android: Broadcast Image Continuously from Service

Tags: android, android-intent, image-processing, memory-management, computer-vision

Hi,
I am working on image processing on Android for my robotics project. In my project, I have 3 Services: CameraService, VisionService, TakePictureService.

- **CameraService:** Read Camera Natively using VideoCapture (OpenCV) and broadcast byte[] data via CAMERA_INTENT
- **VisionService:** Receive byte[] data frame, process Face Detection and broadcast location of faces
- **TakePictureService:** Receive byte[] data frame, draw on SurfaceView and save frame to sdcard when faces are in center of images.

The problem is that the system continuously perform GC_FOR_ALLOC to free the previous frame data and allocate new frame. When my application run for a period of time, my device will reboot.

Before reboot happens, logcat shows many GC_FOR_ALLOC without anything else, then some FAILED_BINDER_TRANSTION and reboot.

I want to ask if there is any solution to solve this problem. My robot needs to perform non-stop Computer Vision tasks. There are many services that need image data and I can only open Camera once so I need to broadcast byte[] data frame.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of broadcast, you may use AIDL interface, once there is data available from camera, you call a interface of VisionService from cameraService, broadcast is not suitable for such job becasue you need to pass large amount of data

Comment: Thank you very much. I used Bind Service and solved this problem.